# What documentation do Airbus/Boeing supply at initial delivery of an aircraft?

Tags: airbus, boeing, aircraft-manufacturer, new-airplane

What are the Aircraft Documents supplied by Boeing and/or Airbus at first delivery? Do they supply Form 8130 or Certificates of Compliance for every part? Or is the AIR/ARL all that is supplied?